# Can co-parents-in-law marry? For example, a husband's father and a wife's mother (but applied to Islam)

Tags: nikah

Same question as [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41600/can-co-parents-in-law-marry-for-example-a-husbands-father-and-a-wifes-mother) but for Islam. I don't see how a married couple's becoming step-siblings is any different from step-siblings' become a married couple.

Suppose Alice and Bob are widows (or single adoptive parents or unmarried biological parents or whatever) and their respective children are Charlie and Dalia. Supposed all 4 are not married (or were never married or whatever, depends if widow or not).

If Alice and Bob marry, then Charlie and Dalia cannot marry. But if Charlie and Dalia marry, then can Alice and Bob marry afterwards?

Comment: Ignoring any complications that might arise out of milk kinship: Step-siblings are not mahrams in Islam. So Charlie and Dalia can marry, even after Alice and Bob marry. 
Similarly Alice can marry Bob, even after Charlie and Dalia are married.

Comment: Yeah well apparently in secular law and in Christianity it's the same thing. XD Any source? I wasn't able to see in that link exactly.

Comment: If you don't see a case mentioned then by default it is permissible to marry that person as it comes under the general permission give by verses like 'And lawful to you are [all others] beyond these' — [Quran 4:24](http://quran.com/4/24) , 'marry those that please you of [other] women' —  [Quran 4:3](https://quran.com/4/3?translations=20) ,  'marry the unmarried among you'  — [Quran 24:32](https://quran.com/24/32?translations=20).

Comment: @UmH Devil's proof? If I didn't find, then doesn't mean it's not actually there. I really wish you could have a source that talks about this. Like perhaps some imam or something was asked by someone and then the imam discusses it in a blog. Idk. Alternative question: May step-siblings marry in Islam?

Comment: Maybe you do not understand my response. Suppose the Quran says that x,y and z are forbidden and all other are permissible. Now if I ask you whether w is permissible then what would be your response? What proof do you think would be needed for it? Logically the answer is that w is permissible since it is not x,y, or z. The same situation applies to your question.

Comment: @UmH the key point is whether or not 'and all other are permissible' is said right?